# Rotating multiple images with different speed in xml

Tags: android, android-animation

My requirement is to rotate multiple images on top of each other. I can do this programmatically but I would prefer to do it from xml.

I have tried to use an animated-rotate but it seems with this solution I can't control the duration of the animation. Also for some reason after the first frame the resolution of the images degrades.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <animated-rotate
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
</item>
<item>
    <animated-rotate
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
</item>
<item>
    <animated-rotate
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
</item>
```

So my question is, if there is a good solution for doing all this from xml?